# Ffmpeg converting video from DVR

Tags: ffmpeg

Tell me how to split and convert video recorded from a DVR that has recording from several cameras ch1, ch2, ch3 and split the video into several video files, from each camera into its own video file?

I didn't find the information I needed in the instructions